# Socket Programming in Python to transfer file in windows

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote(referred from internet bogotobogo.com) a program in python for Client Server communication. When I run it in my Windows 10 its showing the below error : 
**ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Server Code :

```
    import socket
    PORT = 60000
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST,PORT))
        s.listen(5)
        print ("Server Listening...")
        while True:
            conn,addr = s.accept()
            print("Got Connection from ",addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print("Server received", repr(data))
            filename = 'mytext.txt'
            f = open(filename,'rb')
            l = f.read(1024)
            while(l):
                conn.send(l)
                print('Sent ', repr(1))
                l = f.read(1024)
                f.close()
                print("Done Sending")
                conn.send("Thank you for connecting")
                conn.close()
```

Client Code :

```
    import socket
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 60000
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST,PORT))
        s.send("Hello Server")
        with open('received file','wb') as f:
            print('opened file')
            while True:
                print('receiving data...')
                data = s.recv(1024)
                print('data=%s',(data))
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)
            f.close()
        print('Successfully get the file')
        s.close()
        print('Connection Closed')
```

Can you please let me know where I have gone wrong

Comment: Hi Venkat, you should check firewall settings if it allows your program to receive packets.

Comment: Actually I tried another socket programming for exchanging string which worked perfectly. But this one didn't work